# Command operating with several viewmodels

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I'm designing the WPF application architecture by the MVVM pattern. And now I'm having the following situation:

```
class ParentViewModel : ViewModelBase<IParent>
{
    public ObservableCollection<ChildViewModel> Children { get; private set; }
}

class ChildViewModel : ViewModelBase<IChild>
{
    public ICommand ParentAndChildCommand { get; private set; }
}

class ParentAndChildCommand : ICommand
{
    public void Execute(object parameter)
    {
        // ParentViewModel.DoSomething(ChildViewModel);
    }

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        // return CanExecute(ParentViewModel, ChildViewModel);
    }
}
```

The only solution I can see so far is to handle Executing and QueryCanExecute events of the ParentAndChildCommand in the ParentViewModel class. But I believe that there is much better solution for this case. Please advise how to design the logic like that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This is very general question. Please, describe your particular situation, what excacly you can't implement. Otherwise, please read more about MVVM implementation

Comment: What's your problem? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a collection of Parent objects and each of them has his own collection of Child objects. Every Child object has his commands (called from a ContextMenu of the TreeView), but these commands depends on the Parent objects so that to execute the Child command I have to know which Parent does the Child object belong to. I can make the "Parent" property in the Child object or some events in the Child class to handle on the Parent object. But I feel that you can advise me better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

for organization work with ICommand better way using different MVVM frameworks

sample:
http://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/